# Wordpress ajax contact form doesn't return data

Tags: wordpress, jquery

I'm making a WordPress theme where every post will have a contact form. The contact form will collect information about the visitor and send a mail to the site administrator. It will also send an email to the visitor with a link to a downloadable PDF (this code is not done yet).

The problem I have is that the php function that handles the ajax form doesn't respond. It only returns a -1 (No Properties). But I get a status code 200 OK.

I'm running the dev server on MAMP Pro OSX and DynDNS.

**This is the PHP I have in functions.php**

```
function ajax_contact() {

  if(!empty($_POST)) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $company = $_POST['company'];
  $mail = $_POST['mail'];
  $admin_mail = get_bloginfo('admin_email');
  $error = "";
  if(!$name) {
      $error .= "Please tell us your name<br/>";
  }
  if(!$company) {
      $error .= "Please tell us your company<br/>";
  }
  if(!$mail) {
      $error .= "Please tell us your E-Mail address<br/>";
  }

  if(empty($error)) {
      $subject = "New download notification";
      $message = "You've received a new download notification. \n\n
          Name: ".$name."\n
          Company: ".$company."\n
          Mail: ".$mail."\n";

      // Send a mail to the admin with the contact info.    
      $send_mail = wp_mail($admin_mail, $subject, $message);

      // Send mail to visitor with the download link.

      if($send_mail) {
      echo "sent";
      die();
      }

  } else {
      echo "error: " . $error;
      die();
    }
  }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_contact', 'ajax_contact');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_contact','ajax_contact');
```

**This is the javascript code**

```
    function sendForm(formId, postId, str)
{

    console.log("formId: " + formId);
    console.log("formId: " + postId);
    console.log("str: " + str);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        action: "ajax_contact",
        data: str,
        success: function(data) {

            $("#" + formId).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){

            if(data == 'sent') {
                $("#" + formId).find(".success").fadeIn("slow");
                }
                else {
                result = data;
                $("#" + formId).siblings(".success").html(result);
                }
            });

        }
    });


}
```

***And this is the actual form (I have multiple forms on the same page)***

```
<form name="form-<?php the_ID(); ?>" id="form-<?php the_ID(); ?>"/>
    Name <br/> 
    <input type="text" name="name" value=""/><br />
    Company / Organisation <br/> 
    <input type="text" name="company" value=""/><br />
    Email <br/> 
    <input type="text" name="mail" value=""/><br />

    <input type="hidden" name="postId" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>">

    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="requestbutton" id="requestButton-<?php the_ID(); ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>"/>
  </form>
```

**EDIT: Changed the ajax action name, problem still persists**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AJAX `action:` should be `contact_form` not `ajax_contact`

Comment: Changed it now. I still have the same problem. Do you think this could have anything do to with the fact that I use a local dev environment (Same origin)?

Comment: Check your inspector in your browser to see if you are posting your data and what your response is.  Check the network tab and look for your ajax call.

Comment: I've checked the headers and the response in the inspector.

This is the form data:

name:Bill 
company:IBM
mail:bill@ibm.com
postId:48

Request headers:
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:22
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 08 Jun 2012 15:45:22 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.17
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1

Response:
-1

Comment: The `action:contact_form` needs to be part of the post data.

Comment: Thank you Nick! It works now :D The solution (in the javascript code) was data: 'action=ajax_contact&'+str,